# Pandas create a new data frame from counting rows into columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have something like this data frame:

```
  item  color
0    A    red
1    A    red
2    A  green
3    B    red
4    B  green
5    B  green
6    C    red
7    C  green
```

And I want to count the times a color repeat for each item and group-by it into columns like this:

```
  item  red  green
0    A    2      1
1    B    1      2
2    C    1      1
```

Any though? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab(df['item'], df['color'])`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma It solved the task! thanks